# Бот не реагирует на нажатие кнопки?

Tags: python, aiogram

```
class FsmHandler(StatesGroup):
    qiwi = State()
    kesh = State()


@dp.callback_query_handler(text = 'no_pay')
async def no_pay(call: types.CallbackQuery):

    await FsmHandler.qiwi.set()
    await call.message.answer("Введите реквизиты для вывода")


#
async def fsm_1(message: types.Message,state: FSMContext):
    await FsmHandler.next()
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["qiwi"] = message.text

    await message.answer("Введите сумму вывода")
#
async def fname_2(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    #await state.finish()
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["kesh"] = message.text
        amo = data.get("kesh")
        rek = data.get('qiwi')


    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    but1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Принят", callback_data=f"qq_{message.from_user.id}")
    but2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Отклонит", callback_data=f"noy_{message.from_user.id}")
    keyboard.add(but1, but2)
    await bot.send_message(961145889,f"Новая заявка на вывод\n{amo},{rek}",reply_markup = keyboard)
    await message.answer("Заявка отправленна,ожидайте")
    user_id = int(message.from_user.id)
    print(but1)
    print(user_id)

#эта часть кода не работает!Почему?
    @dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith=f"qq_{message.from_user.id}")
    async def qqqq(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
        await bot.send_message(961145889,f"Пользователь {user_id} принят ")
        await bot.send_message(user_id,"Вы приняты")
        await callback.message.delete()
        #ass = db.get_register(message.from_user.id)
        print(f'айди   {user_id}')




    @dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith=f"noy_{message.from_user.id}")
    async def noj(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
        await bot.send_message(961145889,f"Вывод для пользователя {user_id}  отклонен")
        await bot.send_message(user_id,"Вывод отклонен свяжитесь с админом ")
        await callback.message.delete()
```

Comment: Какой кнопки?__

Comment: принять и отклонить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменяй на это

```
dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith=f"qq_")

dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith=f"noy_")
```

Comment: у меня в другом файле есть  @dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)  если я записать эти хендлеры туда то они работаю, но в другом файле они не воспринимаются как сделать так чтобы  он их видел ?Я думаю нужно сделать более узкий фильт -как?

Comment: Перестать делайте запись типа `@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)`, а сделать нормальный фильтр.

Comment: у меня создаются рандомные келлбеки и мне нужко как то их ловить

Comment: Значит к рандому добавьте префикс и этот префикс ловите

Comment: как тогда будет выглядит фильтр?

Comment: так же как и те которые в ответе

Comment: все я понял вас -все работает